# Order of evaluation , unicode string & format

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, unicode, format

Here are a lot of strings in unicode map.

```
unicode_strings = ["\U00000{:0>3}".format(str.upper(hex(i))[2:]) for i in range(16)]
```

but this code emits an error message.

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-6: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

This causes because of the order of evaluation.

First, "\U00000" is evaluated, Second, `format` is executed.

As the error message, unicode character must be the block of "\UXXXXXXXX".

Unicode characters are evaluated at the first time, but this is not the appropriate block at that time.

At the time the format function is executed, the unicode characters must be constructed completely.

I know the cap string 'r' can escape this error message, but it makes no unicode string.

How should I attach "\U" to the string or execute the format function at the first time?

If I delete '\U', the result is utopia.

```
 ['00000001',
 '00000002',
 '00000003',
 '00000004',
 '00000005',
 '00000006',
 '00000007',
 '00000008',
 '00000009',
 '0000000A',
 '0000000B',
 '0000000C',
 '0000000D',
 '0000000E',
 '0000000F']
```

UPDATE:
I want such a result.

```
['\U00000001',
 '\U00000002',
 '\U00000003',
 '\U00000004',
 '\U00000005',
 '\U00000006',
 '\U00000007',
 '\U00000008',
 '\U00000009',
 '\U0000000A',
 '\U0000000B',
 '\U0000000C',
 '\U0000000D',
 '\U0000000E',
 '\U0000000F']
```

I want to get the sequence of characters in Unicode map.

Comment: Doesn't `list(map(chr, range(16)))` produce your desired output?

Comment: So what is your desired output?

Comment: @schwobaseggl  you mean `def m(i):  return ["\U00000{:0>3}".format(str.upper(hex(i))[2:])] list(map(m, range(16))) `? I think this causes same error.

Comment: No, my snippet replaces the entire comprehension: `unicode_strings = list(map(chr, range(16)))`

Comment: @schwobaseggl good advice, but for example, list(map(chr, range(12000, 12065))) take unexpected map. I expect cuneiform from \U00012000 but it gets CJK...

Comment: @Haru You have to use hexadecimal literals: `list(map(chr, range(0x12000, 0x12065)))`. Decimal 12000 is hexadecimal 0x2ee0, which is inside the CJK Radicals Supplement block.

Comment: `12000 == 0x2ee0` so for that range I'd expect to see `\U00002ee0` in your example. Actually `"\U00002ee" + "0"` even.

Comment: Oh... I understood! thanks. yes, it is my desired Output.

Comment: Also note. You will not see it represented as `'\U00000001'` but `'\x01'`, both represent the same character. `print(["\U00000001"])` -> `['\x01']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what exactly are you after, but given that for instance `\U00000000` is the same as `\x00` and to generate this list a following comprehension would seem to make more sense anyways:

```
unicode_strings = [chr(i) for i in range(16)]
```

If the question was why does this happen, the [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) docs may be a little subtle about it:*)

> The string on which this method is called can contain literal text or replacement fields delimited by braces `{}`... Returns a copy of the string where each replacement field is replaced with the string value of the corresponding argument.

But basically the literal strings and "replacement fields" are identified and each is considered as such. In your case a string literal `\U00000` is being considered and is invalid as four bytes hex values are expected following `\U`. Or in other words, it's not really a matter of order (literal firsts, expressions later), but how does the `str` get split into chunks / processed (literals and expressions are identified first and processed as such).

So if you were trying to do something like that for a larger string generation, you could do it as follows:

```
somelist = [f"abcd{chr(i)}efgh" for i in range(16)]
```

---

*) [PEP-498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#specification) on f-strings may be a bit more explicit (and the mechanics are the same in this respect), namely:

> f-strings are parsed in to literal strings and expressions...
>
> The parts of the f-string outside of braces are literal strings. These literal portions are then decoded. For non-raw f-strings, this includes converting backslash escapes such as `'\n'`, `'\"'`, `"\'"`, `'\xhh'`, `'\uxxxx'`, `'\Uxxxxxxxx'`, and named unicode characters `'\N{name}'` into their associated Unicode characters.